# Show that a sequence $\{s_n\}$ converges to a limit $L$ if and only if the sequence $\{s_n-L\}$ converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm looking for hints and ideas on how to improve the draft of my proof.

Proof: Let $\{s_n\}$ be any given sequence. Then take the limit of the sequence {$s_n$} as shown.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n=L $$

Indeed, as $n$ tends to infinity, the sequence converges to $L$.

Once more, we take the difference of the sequence $\{s_n\}$ and the limit $L$.

Lastly, we take the limit of $\{s_n -L\}$, so

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n - L = 0$$

Therefore, the sequence $\{s_n - L\}$ converges to zero.

Comment: You really need to edit this!

Comment: Are $\{a_n\}$ and $\{s_n\}$ two different sequences or the same sequence? EDIT: Thanks for editing to clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. By definition, $s_n \to L$ means that  a positive integer $N$ can be chosen so that for all $n > N $, we have

$$ |s_n - L | < \epsilon $$

Let $a_n = s_n - L $. Hence, $a_n \to 0 $ or $s_n - L \to 0 $. Similarly, you prove the other direction.

Comment: Your explanation was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First of all, you need a clear definition of what it means for a sequence of real numbers to converge to a limit.

Secondly, using this definition of convergence, show that $s_n$ converges to $L$, *if* one assumes that $s_n{}-{}L$ converges to $0$.

Finally, using this definition of convergence again, show that $s_n{}-{}L$ converges to $0$, *if* one assumes that $s_n$ converges to $L$.

This follows the typical structure of an *if, and only if*, proof [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if).

Answer (score 0):

Try a short, and imo clear if the definitions are understood, chain of if and only if arguments:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=L\iff\;\forall\,\epsilon>0\;\exists\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t. \;\;n>N_\epsilon\implies |s_n-L|<\epsilon\iff$$

$$\iff\forall\,\epsilon>0\;\exists\,N_\epsilon\in\Bbb N\;\;s.t.\;\; n>N_\epsilon\implies |(s_n-L)-0|<\epsilon \iff$$

$$\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n-L)=0$$